# How can I disable the Command+Esc shortcut for opening Front Row on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, front-row

I am constantly pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> on accident and whenever I do, Front Row opens. Is there any way to keep this from activating Front Row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Preferences.
[image]